# Adding a Documentation Section

Tags: feature-request

Some questions here are answered in the most intuitive way in the world. I wonder why not gather all pertinent high voted answers in form of tutorials, something like what it is done in https://stackoverflow.com/documentation .

Comment: It's a beta of SO so far.